# Facebook unreliably reading OpenGraph attributes when publishing to newsfeed through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-opengraph

We have a Facebook app that publishes URLs to a user's newsfeed via the Facebook iOS SDK. These URLs are for pages that have OpenGraph attributes defined and we've verified in the Facebook Linter that it's correctly defined.

However, periodically we are seeing that Facebook won't correctly parse the OpenGraph attributes and have less than a stellar post to Facebook:

We will most often get posts parsed correctly resulting in posts like these:

[image]

We'll periodically get posts like these:

[image]

However, you can see this later post works correctly in the FB Url Linter: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fchewsy.com%2Fr%2Fa%2F1bhLT.

However, sometimes the URL Linter will report a 503 but I see nothign in our logs. And even more odd, when the URL Linter reports the 503, it will shows that it can read the OpenGraph attributes defined. See this screenshot:

[image]

Since this is inconsistent, my first guess was this was a Facebook issue so I opened [a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/254329527973289?browse=search_4f416c576b90f7b80935980).  However, since I'm not seeing this issue rampant in the newsfeed with other apps, I'm starting to wonder if we aren't following the right steps to publishing FB content.

For example, are we supposed to post to the URL Linter first, then publish via the Graph API?  This seems like a ridiculous extra step, but I'm grasping at straws here...

Comment: My site is behind Cloudflare.com, and I just got off an email support thread with them where they've acknowledged that the issue is between them and Facebook and are looking to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to fact that in a time Facebook Linter visited your site it wasn't accessible, just couple of refreshes on a Linter Tool with URL you've provided resulted in `Bad Response Code` error, returning `503` status code:

http://chewsy.com/r/a/1bhLT&quot;">

You should dig in logs of your application/site to discover the real reason why this happen and fix it.

Comment: I updated my original post to address this. The URL linter will sometimes report a 503, but I don't see anything in my logs indicating this. Also, when the linter reports this, it still displays OpenGraph attributes its read from the page (see screenshot added)

Comment: @TMC, it show you cached version of tags that was available before error happen, but if this error occurs on first time Linter visit your page this will be exactly what you see on picture #2...

Comment: @TMC, also according [`echo`](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fchewsy.com%2Fr%2Fa%2F1bhLT) of Linter your site returns no data once error occurs. If you can't see it in logs, than probably you're not logging everything. You can try to enable `debug` or `info` log level and see what you get once Linter hit your page. Apparently I cannot reproduce this error via other tools like [hurl](http://hurl.it). So it may be not on your end, if so, file a BUG on [Facebook Bug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create)

Comment: My site is behind Cloudflare.com and based on an email thread I have with them, it looks like it's their issue not mine.

Comment: @TMC, it may be so. It doesn't really matter who is responsible for this, until this happens you will periodically get posts without meta...

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note that this should no longer be happening for CloudFlare users. We pushed a fix for the 503 debugger issue moments ago that appears to have fixed the problem. Please [contact us](http://support.cloudflare.com/) if you see any other issues with the Facebook Debugger.